# What is the best way to alias class and method names

Tags: database, class, dynamic, methods, alias

Here's my situation.  I have a database with string data.  I'm implementing tokens which essentially are "class.method" format to implement dynamic data generation.

For example a column's data might be: 'Hotel $(Generate.GUID)'

Where Generate is a class i've created and GUID is a method of the class.

To keep DB data to a minimum i'd like to alias calls like this for example: 'Hotel $(g.guid)'

I'd like to avoid altering the class with additional shortname methods.  I'm looking for a clean streamlined way to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

The way that would result in the cleanest code and that is the most readable is keeping the full names. Sometimes that bit of extra data is worth the cost.

An alternative is having a mapping table

```
Full      Short
---------------
Generate  g
GUID      guid
```

Then:

```
Hotel $(g.guid)
```

Then, in code, you can either read this table into memory during start-up or whenever, or (the more readable, more error-prone option) have this mapping defined in the code as well.

Comment: We'll try to stick with full names for now.  We need this option in case limitations get hit and in SQL CE that's very easy to do.